# Case-insensitive match multiple search words in text and wrap them in <strong> HTML tags

Tags: php, string, replace, cpu-word, case-insensitive

I'm trying to make search terms bold in this search script that I'm making. The trouble is that I can't get it to work case insensitively.

```
function highlight($term,$target){
    $terms = explode(" ", $term);
    
    foreach($terms as $term){
        $result = (eregi_replace($term, "<strong>$term</strong>", $target));
    }
    return $result;
}
```

That is the function I have so far. It says on PHP.net that `eregi_replace()` is case-insensitive, but it's obviously not working for some reason.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `ereg_*` (POSIX regular expression) functions are [deprecated](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php) as of PHP 5.3 and have not been suggested for a long time. It is better to use the [PCRE](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/intro.pcre.php) (`preg_*`) functions (such as [`preg_replace`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)).

You can do so by creating a case-insensitive regular expression, and then wrapping matches in `<strong>` tags:

```
function highlight($term, $target)
{
  $terms = array_unique(explode(" ", $term)); // we only want to replace each term once
  foreach ($terms as $term)
  {
    $target = preg_replace('/\b(' . preg_quote($term) . ')\b/i', "<strong>$1</strong>", $target);
  }

  return $target;
}
```

What this does is first call [`preg_quote`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) on your `$term` so that if there are any characters that have meaning in a regular expression in the term, they are escaped, then creates a regular expression that looks for that term surrounded by word boundaries (`\b` -- so that if the term is "good" it won't match "goodbye"). The term is wrapped in parentheses to make the regular expression engine capture the term in its existing form as a "backreference" (a way for the regular expression engine to hang on to parts of a match). The expression is made case-insensitive by specifying the `i` option. Finally, it replaces any matches with that same backreference surrounded by the `<strong>` tag.

```
$string = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quicker brown fox didn't jump over the lazy dog.";
$terms = "quick fox";
highlight($terms, $string);
// results in: The <strong>quick</strong> brown <strong>fox</strong> jumped over the lazy dog. The quicker brown <strong>fox</strong> didn't jump over the lazy dog.
```

If you'd like a good tutorial on regular expressions, check out the tutorial on [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Comment: `str_ireplace` will turn `Clock` in the text into `clock` if the user searched for `clock`. Not a good option.

Comment: @Pekka, he asked for case insensitive matching, why is it not a good option. It does just that..

Comment: @this I think he's making a pretty clear statement: `Ok I'm trying to make search terms bold in this search script I'm making`

Comment: I'm giving my upvote to the first answerer presenting a finished, PCRE based example. :)

Comment: So what can I do to combat this issue?

Comment: it would be much faster to call `preg_replace()` only once with arrays.

Comment: This snippet breaks when the search term contains a forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

```
function highlight($term,$target)
{
    $terms = explode(" ", $term);

    foreach($terms as $term){
        $target = (str_ireplace($term, "<strong>$term</strong>", $target));
    }
    return $target;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a dynamic, case-insensitive regex pattern that respects word boundaries, then wrap all replacements in strong tags.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/v3eiq))

```
$safeWords = array_map('preg_quote', explode(' ', 'hat cat'));
$text = 'Cat in the hat that had cataract surgery';

$regex = '#\b(?:' . implode('|', $safeWords) . ')\b#iu';

echo preg_replace($regex, '<strong>$0</strong>', $text);
```

Output:

```
<strong>Cat</strong> in the <strong>hat</strong> that had cataract surgery
```

In comparison to Daniel's script, my script will always only make one pass over the input string to make replacements which means it will:

1. Perform faster when testing with an array of unique terms,
2. Not replace replacement,
3. And therefore cannot create nested tags.